# Windows установить прокси с аутентификацией

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi, proxy

Я изменяю настройки прокси сервера windows с помощью

```
RegistryKey registry = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);
registry.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
registry.SetValue("ProxyServer", "adress:port");

settingsReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
refreshReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

Как можно по схожему принципу установить прокси, требующие аутентификации в виде логина и пароля?

Answer (score 2):

Точно так же, только в дополнении к установке прокси задать опции `INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_USERNAME` и `INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_PASSWORD`. По идее лучше и прокси устанавливать не ковырянием в реестре, а опцией `INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY`.